# How do I extract text that lies between two indicators?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a long string with a number of "merge fields", all of the merge fields will be in the following format: `<<FieldName>>`.

The string will have multiple merge fields of different type i.e. `<<FirstName>>`, `<<LastName>>`

How can I loop through the string and find all the merge fields so that I can replace the field with the text?

I will not know all the different Merge fields in the string, the user may enter anything between the two indicators i.e. `<<Anything>>`

I ideally would like to stay away from any regex but happy to explore all options.

Comment: @erkandemir The author wrote "I ideally would like to stay away from any regex.", so that's not an option.

Comment: If FieldName is known in advance, you can simply replace(), otherwise find <<, store position, find >> from that position - you then have start & end so can concatenate left+new_text+right, repeat until no more <<

Comment: Avoiding regex for this task is like avoiding a hammer when trying to bang in nails. Right tool, right job.

Comment: @Jamiec RegEx is still *optional*, I don't see any flaw in avoiding it as it's somewhat a new language that needs get understood, parsed, compiled etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RegularExpression makes most sense here

```
string text = "foo <<FieldName>> foo foo <<FieldName>> foo";
string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"[<]{2}\w*[>]{2}", "bar", RegexOptions.None);
```

**UPDATE** without RegEx - after the question got updated:

```
Dictionary<string, string> knownFields = new Dictionary<string, string> {    {"<<FirstName>>", "Jon"},    {"<<LastName>>", "Doe"},    {"<<Job>>", "Programmer"}};
string text = "Hello my name is <<FirstName>> <<LastName>> and i work as a <<Job>>";
knownFields.ToList().ForEach(x => text = text.Replace(x.Key, x.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you want to avoid regular expressions, but it's the right tool for the job.

```
Dictionary<string,string> fieldToReplacement = new Dictionary<string,string> {
    {"<<FirstName>>", "Frank"},
    {"<<LastName>>", "Jones"},
    {"<<Salutation>>", "Mr."}
};

string text = "Dear <<Salutation>> <<FirstName>> <<LastName>>, thanks for using RegExes when applicable. You're the best <<FirstName>>!!";
string newText = Regex.Replace(text, "<<.+?>>", match => {
    return fieldToReplacement[match.Value];
});

Console.WriteLine(newText);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/HPfHph

Answer (score -3):

As @Alex K. wrote, you need to search for the indices of the start and end tag, like so:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string text = "<<FieldName>>";
        const string startTag = "<<";
        const string endTag = ">>";
        int offset = 0;
        int startIndex = text.IndexOf(startTag, offset);
        if(startIndex >= 0) {
            int endIndex = text.IndexOf(endTag, startIndex + startTag.Length);
            if(endIndex >= 0) {
                Console.WriteLine(text.Substring(startIndex + startTag.Length, endIndex - endTag.Length));
                //prints "FieldName"
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works for a single field. The OP wants to parse a string like "blah blah <<FieldName1>> some other blahblah <<FieldName2>><<FieldName3>>blahblah" *and* he also wants to replace the fields with some values.

Comment: This was an example to show the idea how to "extract text that lies between two indicators" (**the title**). I even put an *offset* in the code in advance. Roughly said, there is only a for-each loop missing over the string to test.

Comment: this replaces the whole text between the first and the last <<FieldName>>

Comment: @fubo yes, you got it.